# Which process comes first?

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, process-scheduling

Let's say we have 3 processes:

- Process 1 service time 6 arrival time 0
- Process 2 service time 2 arrival time 1
- Process 3 service time 5 arrival time 3

We know that:

- after 1 time, process 2 will come and process 1 will go back having 5 service time left.
- then process 3 will come, after process 2 ends, at 3 time.

Now the conflict is:

Since process 1 and process 3 have equal service time - which one gets service time first?

Comment: Have you copy-pasted a table here? Please take more care with language and formatting; I find it hard to tell what you are asking. Community votes, please! Is this unclear?

Comment: @Raphael - It sort of makes sense: As process 1 was pushed into the background (with 5 service time slots remaining) while process 2 was being serviced, then (at time slot 3) as process 3 also requires 5 service slots, which process has precedence, process1 or process 3..?

Comment: It would help if you could edit the post to use full sentences.  I don't know what "Process 1 service time 6 arrival time 0" means.  I also don't know what "at 3 time" means.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the scheduling algorithm. Most of the scheduling algorithms will decide arbitrary. I assume that you are talking about shortest-job-first. SJF will schedule arbitrarily.

The real life scheduling algorithms are round-robin as we usually do not know the completion time. And they usually want to give a quick response to a new job. These algorithms will schedule process 3.